# Convert result into where criteria

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query which reads from a set of test criteria in a table and formulates a string to be used as a WHERE condition.

```
select STRING_AGG(stepexpr, ' or ')
from (
   select '(step = ' || step || ' and ' || STRING_AGG(column_name || ' > ' || lower || ' and ' || column_name || ' < ' || upper, ' and ') || ')' stepexpr
   from criteria
   group by step
) t;
```

This query, with my criteria data set results in the following:

```
(step = 1 and temperature > 20 and temperature < 30 and voltage > 9 and voltage < 11) or (step = 2 and temperature > 50 and temperature < 60 and voltage > 14 and voltage < 16)
```

The issue that I have is I want to use that result string and formulate a query from that results... for instance:

```
SELECT * FROM test_data WHERE 
(step = 1 and temperature > 20 and temperature < 30 and voltage > 9 and voltage < 11) or 
(step = 2 and temperature > 50 and temperature < 60 and voltage > 14 and voltage < 16)
```

It seems trivial but I cannot seem to get it to work!

Comment: Outside of a stored procedure I'm not sure this can be made to work.

Comment: klin, when I run your query, it returns a string back as well... so I'm not quite sure how to take that returned result and execute it as a query.  I do agree though, your solution did provide the proper query back... again, I just don't know how to translate that returned query into an actual data set

Comment: If you want to execute it, you will have to use dynamic sql in plpgsql, and therefore either a function or an anonymous DO block.

Comment: This is not trivial.  SQL statements and strings are *different* things.  What connects them are dynamic SQL, which you can execute in a function.